# non-transaction SQL Migration via Flyway

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, flyway, full-text-indexing

im trying to create Full Text Catalogs in SQL and migrating all the scripts via Flyway but im getting an error when I try to migrate Full Text Catalogs.

```
Migration V1_5__FullTextSearch.sql failed
-------------------------------
SQL State  : S1000
Error Code : 574
Message    : CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.
Location   : C:/Users/User1/Desktop/flyway-3.2.1/sql/V1_5__FullTextSearch.sql (C:\Users\User1\Desktop\flyway-3.2.1\sql\V1_5__FullTextSearch.sql)
Line       : 152
Statement  : EXEC sp_CreateFullTextSearch
```

Is there a Way to avoid Flyway's enforcement on user transactions or any workaround in order to create FullText Catalogs.

PD:

Im creating the FullText Catalogs on a stored procedure but im having the same luck:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CreateFullTextSearch
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FullTextQuery AS nvarchar(MAX)= N'
    IF not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs
       WHERE name = ''MerchantSearchCat'') 
    begin
        CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG MerchantSearchCat
        AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    end

    IF not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs
       WHERE name = ''IndividualSearchCat'') 
    begin
        CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG IndividualSearchCat
        AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    end

    IF not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs
       WHERE name = ''CustomerSearchCat'') 
    begin
        CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG CustomerSearchCat
        AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    END

    IF not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs
       WHERE name = ''ItemSearchCat'') 
    begin
        CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ItemSearchCat
        AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    END'

    EXEC sp_executesql @FullTextQuery
END
```

Comment: I kinda solve the problem, to avoid the User Transaction error I used this line:

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;